# Jquery + Json + Write json object inside a file using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

In one of the functionality, I want to put latest json file on client side to show data rather than internet connectivity lost message with last updated time.

As the internet comes to work, then using ajax call I will put the latest json value on client side.

> But the problem is like when I call ajax call it give json object, now
>   I want to write that json object inside any file like sample_json.json
>   file. I am not getting the way to store the content inside the file
>   using Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery, like JavaScript is client side language, and as such it can't access local file system (because of security reasons).

What you can do is save your JSON into localstorage. Your content will be written into file and even better, locastorage is used as JSON storage.

Only downside I can think of is that this technology is limited to HTML5 enabled browsers.

Read more about it **[here](http://samcroft.co.uk/2013/using-localstorage-to-store-json/)**, I'm not related to this blog.

Or you can take a look at this micro framework: **[Lawnchair.js](http://brian.io/lawnchair/)**, it uses several kind of saving methods depending on used browser. You don't need to worry how and where is everything stored, this framework will gracefully use any possible method available. You only need to use it as a wrapper.

Comment: Yes, you are Right. But here I dnt have any local database. So I have to download the json file and put some where on client side to render the data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for Reference Link .. I am looking for something like that.

Comment: Don't mix this with client side databases, it is a complete different technology.  I made an update to my answer, take a look.